# Mapbox- are sub categories possible?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-studio

I'm using mapbox to show gravestone locations for a cemetery. Is there a way to have the list on the left be split into 5 items, with subcategories in each? IE: Last names, "A-D", "E-I", etc. and then the actual persons name in the subcategory list?
[image]